# Google Maps API V2 - Binary XML File line #7 : Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I have a map and it's open good when I'm using one include parameter.But when I'm adding in  slider Drawer second type include parameter with exception is throwing.Have to fix it.Thak's for help.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"`enter code here`
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/elm_map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/elm_frg_map" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/view_first"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/elm_view_for_map" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/slider_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle"
        tools:ignore="NestedWeights" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_large_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/edge_above"
            android:background="@color/color_orange" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:allowSingleTap="false"
            android:content="@+id/content"
            android:handle="@+id/handle"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1"
            tools:ignore="NestedWeights,ObsoleteLayoutParam" >

            <include
                android:id="@+id/fg_map_drawer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                layout="@layout/elm_frg_map" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/el_view_drawer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/elm_view_for_map" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_persons"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>
```

and here is my include map element

`<fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                 />`

and my map code

```
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable( getBaseContext() );
if( status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS )
{
  int requestCode = 10;
  mDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog( status, this, requestCode );
  mDialog.show();
}
else
{
  // map fragment
  SupportMapFragment fmap = ( SupportMapFragment )getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById( R.id.map );
  mGMap = fmap.getMap();
}
// click icon
mGMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener( this );

mGps = new UserLocation( MapActivity.this );
// get current user location
mGMap.setMyLocationEnabled( true );
```

Comment: Is that your entire XML? If so, then your XML is not correct because you don't have a single root element. You have a LinearLayout and a SlidingDrawer as siblings with no parent surrounding them.

Comment: Actually I found the problem.The problem was in duplicate id of map fragment.Now it's work good

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I did the mistake to only add one of the 2 following tags. **Note that you are also missing one of these two**

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="<YOUR VALUE>"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

The actual error is really misleading, as you might be thinking of some API level UI issue.